# Setting a ruleset for @@search in Plone plone.app.caching

Tags: caching, plone, varnish

I am hardening my site with Varnish and plone.app.caching is working well except for with every page request is an additional request for /@@search?

Problem is that @@search is always going to the backend (so it seems when i tail the z2.log).

I can see that it is picking up an expire header being set to Jan 1, 2000 ... without monkey patching plone.app.caching how can I stop this request going to the backend so much?

I would prefer not to write a varnish vcl rule for @@search rather would use the plone.app.caching UI to achieve this...

Comment: Apart from the caching question, have you figured out what is causing the /@@search request on each other request? That seems odd.

Comment: No, i thought maybe it was a macro or ajax request as part of the main Plone template? It happens from every page, some of which are custom types some of which are bog standard Plone page types. The only reason i noticed it is that it is accidentally catching a varnish rule to always go to the backend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in IRC, you need a cache:ruleset directive.

```
  <cache:ruleset
      for="plone.app.search.browser.Search"
      ruleset="plone.app.caching.moderateCaching"
      />
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew... I will add a specific ruleset for it as you suggest. I guess in a standard functioning environment it would just pickup 'strongCaching' and not hit the backend ie no rule required... the problem in our config is a dodgy varnish rule that sends anything not specifically set straight to the backend.

Comment: I don't know what the default is for this browser view, but I DO think that it should have a rule added so these things can be configured in the control panel.